# Saving content of TPaintBox Canvas to a Bitmap (and/or a file) in Delphi 10.3 Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, firemonkey

Delphi 10.3.3 Firemonkey App for Android.
I'm drawing a lots of objects in **TPaintBox** **Canvas** in the OnPaint event.
Now I need to save the whole content of **PaintBox.Canvas** in *a Bitmap, and, finally, in a file*.
How this can be done? 
Read RAD docs, googled internet - cannot find a solution.

**UPDATE1:**

Following comments from @MBo  , @Remy-Lebeau , @Adam-Henderson I tried, but it is 50% success only...

I created

```pascal
procedure GameCanvasPaint(Canvas: TCanvas);
```

In PaintBox OnPaint event I'm calling it, drawint successfull:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
  GameCanvasPaint( Canvas );
end;
```

and now I want to create Bitmap and share it, also calling same paining function:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ShowShareSheetAction1BeforeExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
// g_bmp_share is TBitmap already created earlier
  g_bmp_share.SetSize( Paintbox1.Canvas.Width, Paintbox1.Canvas.Height );
  g_bmp_share.Canvas.Clear($FFFFFF);
  GameCanvasPaint( g_bmp_share.Canvas );
  ShowShareSheetAction1.Bitmap.Assign( g_bmp_share );
end;
```

**RESULT:**  Shared picture with *black color... Nothing on it, only black*. **Who can advise why?**

Comment: Often it is wise to draw "a lot of objects" into bitmap (as off-screen buffer) and then draw bitmap onto Paintbox in OnPaint. In this case your problem is solved automatically.

Comment: @MBo If no other solutions will be proposed, then I may try change code to draw on bitmap. Although it is lot of code already in canvas painting.

Comment: @SergeyZubkov move the drawing code into a reusable function that takes a canvas as input, then you can have your OnPaint handler call the function with the TPaintBox canvas, and your save code call the function with a bitmap canvas.

Comment: Example by David Heffernan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360330/1339507)

Comment: MBo  , @Remy-Lebeau , Adam-Henderson I tried, but it is 50% success only...

Comment: @AdamHenderson those examples are for VCL not FMX

Comment: @Remy-Lebeau Yes, but the concept of abstracting out the drawing logic is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your drawing code into a reusable function that takes a `TCanvas` as input, then you can have your `OnPaint` handler call the function with the `TPaintBox` canvas, and your save code call the function with a `TBitmap` canvas.

Note that when you draw on an FMX `TBitmap` canvas, you need to call [`Canvas.BeginScene()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.BeginScene) first:

> Notifies the TCanvas object that the drawing can begin.
>
> **Call BeginScene before drawing on the TCanvas.**
>
> To end the drawing session, call EndScene.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.GameCanvasPaint(Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
  //...
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
  GameCanvasPaint( Canvas );
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowShareSheetAction1BeforeExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // g_bmp_share is TBitmap already created earlier
  g_bmp_share.SetSize( Paintbox1.Width, Paintbox1.Height );
  if g_bmp_share.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    g_bmp_share.Canvas.Clear($FFFFFF);
    GameCanvasPaint( g_bmp_share.Canvas );
  finally
    g_bmp_share.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
  ShowShareSheetAction1.Bitmap.Assign( g_bmp_share );
end;
```

You don't need to do that in the `OnPaint` event as FMX calls `BeginScene()` for you before firing the event:

> Tip: Notice that calling BeginScene in the OnPaint event handlers has no effect, because **BeginScene is called before the OnPaint event handler runs**. This guarantees that painting always occurs in OnPaint without requiring extra and probably unexpected code to allow drawing to have an effect.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly.
Just you have a small typo:

`finally
    g_bmp_share.Canvas.EndScene; // here should be EndScene`

Comment: @SergeyZubkov fixed